# Parent should receive information about the grandchild work completion

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork, real-time

Title says everything. I'm learning operating systems and I want to write a code in C programming language that Parent should receive information about completion of grandchild work. How may I do that using ***fork*** and ***wait***?

The code returns information to parent about child work completion. I want to do the same thing with grandchild.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] ){
   pid_t child, rv; 
   int st;      
   child = fork();
   if( child == 0 ){
      sleep(5);
      return 5;
   }    
   printf( "Child PID = %ld\n", (long)child );  
   rv = wait( &st );    
   printf( "wait() = %ld\nst = %x\n", (long)rv, st );   
   printf( "Child exit code = %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(st) );
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Do you really mean parent and *grand* child, and not just parent and child? And what have you tried so far? How have it worked, or not worked? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets call our processes as follow:

```
t1 - Parent process
t2 - Child process
t3 - Grandchild process
```

The way to do this would be the following flow:

1. `t1` creates child process `t2`
2. `t1` waits for child process `t2` exit status

Now, the parent `t1` process is blocked and waiting for child process `t2` to finish.

1. Make child process `t2` create its own child process `t3`.
2. `t2` waits for child process `t3`.

Now `t3` runs, finishes and returns exit status to parent `t2`. `t2` will run and return that status to its parent `t1`. This way you propagated the exit status of `t3` all the way up to `t1`.